# MySQL Statement with multi nested JOINs and Distinct Limited Ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, left-join

I'm attempting to build a list of results based on three joins

I have created a table of leads, as my sales team takes action on the leads they attach event note records to the leads. 1 lead can have many notes. each note has a timestamp and also a date/time field where they can set a future date in order to schedule call backs and appointments.

I have no trouble building the list, with all my leads associated with their respective event notes, but what I want to do in this particular case is query a smaller list of leads that are associated with only the event note containing the "newest"/highest value in the date_time column.

I've been digging about especially here on stack for the last couple days attempting to get the desired result from my statements. I get either all of the lead records with all of their associated event note records or I get 1, no matter what I utilize ( GROUP BY date_time ASC LIMIT 1) or (ORDER BY date_time ASC LIMIT 1) I've even tried to build a view with only the highest scheduled record for each lead.id.

```
SELECT
  rr_leads.id AS 'Lead', 
  rr_leads.first,
  rr_leads.last,
  rr_leads.company,
  rr_leads.phone,
  rr_leads.email,
  rr_leads.city,
  rr_leads.zip,
  rr_leads.status,
  z.noteid,
  z.taskid,
  z.scheduled,
  z.event

  FROM rr_leads
  LEFT JOIN
      ( 
        SELECT 
    rr_lead_notes.lead_id,
            rr_lead_notes.id AS 'noteid', 
    rr_lead_tasks.id AS 'taskid', 
    rr_lead_notes.date_time AS 'scheduled', 
    rr_lead_notes.task_note, 
    rr_lead_tasks.task_step AS 'event'

        FROM rr_lead_notes
        LEFT JOIN rr_lead_tasks
    ON rr_lead_notes.task_note = rr_lead_tasks.task_step
        AND rr_lead_notes.id IS NOT NULL
        AND rr_lead_notes.task_note IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY rr_lead_notes.id DESC

) z

  ON rr_leads.id = z.lead_id
  WHERE rr_leads.id IS NOT NULL
  AND z.noteid IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY rr_leads.id DESC
```

Comment: Are you asking for a list of leads with only their most recent note?

Comment: That's a lot of code.  I suggest selecting two fields, plus the time_stamp, from 1 table.  Order by the time_stamp desc and limit 1.  Keep building it up until you stop getting the expected result.

Comment: I want to select each lead with only it's most recent/or future event note

Comment: This is the most often requested problem in SO

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general idea of getting data associated with a most recent event.  You can adjust for your particular situation.

```
select yourfields
from table1 join othertables etc
join
(select id, max(time_stamp) maxts
from table1
where whatever
group by id) temp on table1.id = temp.id
and table1.time_stamp = maxts
where whatever
```

Make sure the where clauses in your main query and subquery are the same.